# Enabling Intel Trusted Execution Technology (Intel TXT) causes boot failure?

Tags: bios, tpm

I have Supermicro X11SAE with client TPM and Xeon E3 (v5) installed.
TPM is enabled and seems to work fine.
Secure boot is enabled and seem to work fine as well.
BIOS admin password is set.
When I enable Intel TXT in BIOS system goes into infinite reboot process.
What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I did have the same problem on a brand new SuperMicro Dual Xeon motherboard. I enabled TXT and the machine didn't boot.

My theory: You need to be in UEFI mode for TXT to work.

Comment: Is this what worked for you, or just a theory as to what might work?

Comment: In my case UEFI mode is enabled (otherwise Secure boot wouldn't work).